# indexOf() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I got an array of strings and I'd like to check if any of these strings contain a certain substring.

The following code is an example of what I need to achieve: the function gets a message from an user and searches through a series of URLs the one that contains the user's message in the title:

```
var redditSubModule = "node";
var http = require('https');
var url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/soccerstreams/new/.json";
var i = 0;
var subject =  (ctx.message.text).substring(8);
var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    var json = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        json += chunk;
        });
    response.on('end', function() {
    var redditResponse = JSON.parse(json);
    redditResponse.data.children.forEach(function(child) {
        if(child.data.domain !== 'self.node') {
            url = child.data.url;
            console.log('URL : ' + url);
            if (url.indexOf(subject) > -1) {
                console.log('URL : ' + url);
            } else {
                console.log("nothing...");
            }
            i++;

            }
        }); 
    })
});
request.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

If you try and fill subject with "USA" (because there's a thread with that string in the title) the indexOf doesn't seem to work and it prints a list of "nothing..."
Logging the typeof url gives string as type so I don't know what is going on here... 
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: So give us a running example, give us array and the variable substring

Comment: Code looks ok I think it would be easier if you made a working example. You should put let or var in front of `i = 0`

Comment: (array[i]./*toString().*/indexOf(substring) seems to be strange for me...

Comment: Your  code as posted does in fact work. How do you know your array contains the values you think it does?

Comment: @LeoR. are you confused there is a comment? Just gets removed by the parser

Comment: lol.. no the comment the array[i].indexOf(substring)... dont understand what he wants to do comparing it with -1..

Comment: @LeoR. The `.indexOf()` function returns `-1` when it cannot find the search string in the searched text.

Comment: My guess: the array contents are filled in by an asynchronous mechanism and this code runs before that completes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.find` and `array.prototype.includes`:

```js
var strs = ["aaa", "xxx", "yyy_leon"];
var search = "leon";
var found = strs.find(s => s.includes(search));
if (found) {
  console.log("found: ", found);
} else {
  console.log("nothing");
}
```

Comment: Or `some` if it's just going to be a boolean check